# Cython Install GCC error

Tags: python, gcc, installation, cython

Trying to install Cython on a small VPS running Ubuntu Server. Did

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

and then

```
python setup.py install
```

In the Cython directory, but I get this peculiar error.

```
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'Cython.Plex.Scanners' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c Cython/Plex/Scanners.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/Cython/Plex/Scanners.o
Cython/Plex/Scanners.c:4:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
Cython/Plex/Scanners.c:6:6: error: #error Python headers needed to compile C extensions, please install development version of Python.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Why should I need a 'development version of Python'? Running Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:57:41). Thanks!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need the developer version of Python - i.e. the Python header files (Python.h)

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

Comment: Okay! May I ask why this is necessary? My development machine (Windows) just has the standard Python 2.6 and works okay. Then again, I installed via the packaged installer, so it might have included everything.

Comment: A simple answer would be that some source files in Cython #include some python header files and so you need python headers to compile Cython. If you want to know why those files are being used then you need to look at Cython source.

Comment: This is also due to the fact that Ubuntu and Debian choose to separate the devel packages.

Comment: The standard Windows distribution includes the header files. On certain linuxes, the default installation doesn't (because the distibutors think it's funny to omit them, along with. e.g. parts of the stdlib (tkinter) :/).

Comment: I simply installed `python-devel` in CentOS 7. It may be necessary to know the Python version required in the OS

Answer (score 4):

You need the headers included in the development version of Python, i.e. `python.h`.  It should be packaged in Ubuntu as `python-dev`.